# How to split a layout into four equal parts with Kotlin in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm doing a little exercise on splitting layout into four parts on android studio, even though my code is similar to the one provided [here](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-practice-problems/blob/main/Unit%201/Pathway%203/ComposeQuadrant/app/src/main/java/com/example/composequadrant/MainActivity.kt), but my code is not giving the expected result.

```
@Composable
fun GiaoDien() {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Row(Modifier.weight(1f)){
                WriteText(
                    noidung = stringResource(R.string.noi_dung_1),
                    tieude = stringResource(R.string.tieu_de_1),
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFF8BC34A),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )
                WriteText(
                    noidung = stringResource(R.string.noi_dung_2),
                    tieude = stringResource(R.string.tieu_de_2),
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEADDFF),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )
            }
            Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                WriteText(
                    noidung = stringResource(R.string.noi_dung_3),
                    tieude = stringResource(R.string.tieu_de_3),
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFF03A9F4),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )
                WriteText(
                    noidung = stringResource(R.string.noi_dung_4),
                    tieude = stringResource(R.string.tieu_de_4),
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFA7900D),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )
            }
        }
    }
@Composable
fun WriteText(noidung:String,
              tieude: String,
              backgroundColor: Color,
              modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor).padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = tieude,
            modifier =Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Text(
            text = noidung,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        )
    }
}
```

Result preview code:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Goc__phan_tuTheme {
        GiaoDien()

    }
}
```

Result I got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV6EE.png)

I don't know where I went wrong, please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Help me edit the code.

Comment: can you provide me which output would you want in terms of any image as you expected, cause the code works perfect as it is written.

Comment: My expected output is a layout of four equal parts. My code has a layout of a column block containing two Row blocks but it seems like the 2nd Row block is not implemented, it only displays the 1st Row component  .I still don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Okay, i integrated your code as you provided above and as you said for the four equal part, it is working fine for me providing the four equal part on the ui.

Comment: Thank you for your time on my problem. I think this problem will be resolved when recreating the project.  This is so funny.

Comment: Yeah in compose, studio will provide you the proper UI output when the project is built successfully.